# How does Spiderman's body work internally?

Tags: spider-man, marvel

**How does Spiderman's body work?**

Is he a *combination* of a spider/human or is he a human who has transformed *into* a spider?

I'm interested to know how his body regenerates. As he doesn't seem to sleep in a bed of webs as a normal spider does.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm guessing that English is not your first language. While I can follow part of your question, I think most of us are going to have a real hard time trying to figure out the whole thing - particularly the part about sleep and regeneration.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version of Spider-man some of the details change, mostly to reflect the fears/ideas of the time. Originally Spider-Man was transformed by a bite of a radioactive spider, however the most recent one was a "genetically manipulated spider".

Although there have been story arcs where Spider-Man has become more spider than man:
[image: Peter Parker becoming more spider than man]

This is the best image I could come up with.

I don't think there are any story arcs were he was a spider transformed into a person. He also does not have a "spider inside", although some of his genes have been manipulated to be "spider genes".

Some powers seem to be super abilities of Spider-Man (super agility, "Spidey-Sense") where others are either super powers or technological engineering (web shooters).

In the original story, all of his powers were innate except his webs.

<strike>Spider-Man has no super regeneration that I know of. He is at peak physical shape, but I would not say he has "super regeneration".</strike>

Spider-man has "limited healing factor" http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Man_(Peter_Parker)

There is no indication that his healing has anything to do with sleep or webs.

Spider-Man presumably has to sleep as much as anyone in the peak of their physical endurance.